# Why is proton coupling through bonds and how does this affect identical protons?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I had the opportunity to work with a NMR spectrometer and decided to learn some of the theory behind it. After finishing [Clayden's](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Organic-Chemistry-Jonathan-Clayden/dp/0198503466) chapter on $^{1}\textrm{H}$ NMR (Ch. 11) I'm still left with some questions, mostly concerning coupling.

Proton coupling is described as the interaction between neighboring (2-4 bonds away) protons magnetic field. This can split the signals by a constant amount (the coupling constant), which depend on the environment of the protons but not on the strength of the magnetic field. Ideally creating a binomial distribution when the neighboring protons have the same shift.

- How does a proton create a magnetic field that influences the neighboring protons (mainly) through bonding and not through space?
- Why do identical protons not influence each other? Or more generally: why is it that the more identical the influencing protons are with the influenced proton (i.e. $\Delta\delta$ getting equal to/lower than $J$), the more their "outer" signals vanish? Especially since $J$ is a constant, I would expect that for example two doublets would just merge into one doublet and not into only a singlet.

Comment: coupling constant does not depend so much on the environment but on the distance and connectivity

Answer (score 10):

> How does a proton create a magnetic field that influences the neighboring protons (mainly) through bonding and not through space?

Through space coupling is known as [dipolar coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole%E2%80%93dipole_interaction#Dipolar_coupling_and_NMR_spectroscopy) and is actually much greater than through bond coupling ([J-coupling](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/05-hmr-03-jcoupl.htm)).  However, in low viscosity liquids the chemical shift effects of dipolar coupling are averaged to essentially a single value by molecular rotation.  Relaxation effects of dipolar coupling are still observed.

> Why do identical protons not influence each other?

For two protons there will be four states $\alpha \alpha , \alpha \beta , \beta \alpha$, and $\beta \beta$.   In the general case, each state may have a different energy and there can be four possible one quantum transitions ($\alpha \alpha$ to $\alpha \beta$, $\alpha \alpha$ to $\beta \alpha$, $\alpha \beta$ to $\beta \beta$, and $\beta \alpha$ to $\beta \beta$), each transition having a unique energy and hence 4 peaks (two doublets).

However, when the two protons are equivalent, $\beta \alpha$ and $\alpha \beta$ will be the same energy, $E_2$ let's say.  So, letting the energy of  $\alpha \alpha$ be $E_1$ and $\beta \beta$ be $E_3$, and given a one quantum transition, the possible energies for transtions are only $E_3$ - $E_2$ and $E_2$- $E_1$.  But $E_3$ and $E_1$ are equally spaced above and below $E_2$, so there is only one energy of transition.

For a more-rigorous explanation see: http://www.chemie.uni-hamburg.de/nmr/insensitive/tutorial/en.lproj/energy_levels.html

Answer (score 7):

> How does a proton create a magnetic field that influences the neighboring protons (mainly) trough bonding and not trough space?

A proton doesn't interact with another proton by producing a magnetic field *per se*, but it interacts via the bonding electrons *via* the [Fermi contact interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_contact_interaction). And because the Wikipedia article is kind of dry on this matter, here a figure that very well illustrates what is going on:

[image: Fermi Contact Interaction]

This interaction is not the only source for indirect coupling of spins. If we only consider protons, then we're fine. But if you'd like to consider fluorine-fluorine couplings, you also have to take into account the dipolar interaction between the nuclear and electron spins. This dipolar interaction also provides a source for anisotropic $J$ interactions.

---

> Why do identical protons not influence each other? Or more general: why is it that how more identical the influencing protons are with the influenced proton (i.e. $\Delta\delta$ getting equal to/lower than $J$), the more their "outer" signals vanish? Especially since $J$ is a constant, I would expect that for example two doublets would just merge into one doublet and not into only a singlet.

Also here, a picture is worth more than a thousand words (I'll spare you the calculation of this spectrum):

[image: Spectrum for an interacting two-spin system]

The $k$ is defined as follows:
$$ k = \left| \frac{\Omega_2 - \Omega_1}{2\pi J} \right|$$

As you can clearly see, the outer peaks start getting smaller the smaller the difference in chemical shift ($\Omega$) of the two spins tends towards zero. This is sometimes called ["roof effect"](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Magnetic_Resonance_Spectroscopies/Nuclear_Magnetic_Resonance/NMR%3A_Experimental/NMR_-_Interpretation#High-order_splitting_pattern).

The intensity of the left- and rightmost lines can be calculated (assuming $J>0$) with the following formula:
$$ I_{13} = I_{34} = \frac{1 - \sin(2\alpha)}{4} $$
where
$$ 2\alpha = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\pi J}{\Omega_1 - \Omega_2} \right) $$